# Touch the file to future time stamp

Tags: ksh, aix, touch

I have created the file which is 30 minutes old by using following command

```
TZ=ZZZ0 touch -t "$(TZ=ZZZ0:30 date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" $HOME/reference
```

Similarly how can I create a file 30 minutes of future time.

Ex: at 5:00 PM I want to touch the file to be at 5:30 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a minus sign:

```
TZ=ZZZ0 touch -t "$(TZ=ZZZ-0:30 date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" $HOME/reference
```

Or invert your timezone trick:

```
TZ=ZZZ0:30 touch -t "$(TZ=ZZZ0 date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" $HOME/reference
```

If you need to go beyond the range of timezone offsets, standard shell utilities notoriously lack a way to manipulate date. Various people have done the job of implementing date calculations in Bourne shell, so one option is to download one of these (a few are listed in [Date arithmetic in Unix shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467/date-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-scripts)). Another option is to install [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), specifically its [`date` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#date-invocation) which lets you typeset [dates such as `now + 30 minutes`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Date-input-formats). You can also install a more sophisticated scripting environment such as Perl and use its date manipulation libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use that command:

```
touch -t "$( printf '%(%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)T\n' 'now +30 minutes' )" file
```

With `-t` of `touch` you can specify a date. And wih `ksh`'s printf it is also possible to format a date. with the `%(date-format)T`, see the manual page of `ksh`.

Comment: I have tried this, i got an error `date: 0551-402 Invalid character in date/time specification.` `Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]`

Comment: `date: 0551-402 Invalid character in date/time specification.
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
touch: 0652-141 The specified time format is:[[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]].`

Comment: @Aravind sry, it's AIX.. I changed my answer^^

Comment: I think AIX's [`printf`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/printf.htm?lang=en) doesn't have this format. The manual doesn't distinguish between `/usr/bin/printf` and the ksh93 builtin though, so it's possible that some options are missing.

Answer (score 0):

For the GNU's `touch` pilgrims stumbling upon this question:

You can also use the `-d` parameter of `touch`.

```bash
touch -d "now +30 minutes" $HOME/reference
```

Comment: Unfortunately, [touch for AIX](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=t-touch-command#touch__-d_flag) (as the Q is tagged) does not support the "now +" syntax (as GNU's touch command does).

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for your comment.
I modified the answer to say it.
I find it useful to have the answer here because I also ended up on this question by googling.